# Ruby: Convert Dates in Specific CSV File Column to Year Only

Tags: ruby, csv, date

I am working with a CSV file in Ruby that has multiple columns containing dates.  All but one of the columns I am trying to have Ruby convert the dates to the 4-digit year only.

**Example CSV File:**

(EDIT: Forgot to include that the dates are housed in quotation marks.)

```
name,birthdate,color,year1,fruit,year2
Joe,"1/1/1950",red,"1/18/1989",banana,"2/7/2003"
Joan,"2/4/2007",blue,"3/12/2010",peach,"4/10/2018"
John,"3/22/1979",yellow,"10/4/2009",plum,"11/17/2000"
```

I want to leave the "birthdate" column as is, but I want to change the "year1" and "year2" columns to show the 4-digit year only, so that I have the following results:

**Expected Result:**

```
name,birthdate,color,year1,fruit,year2
Joe,1/1/1950,red,1989,banana,2003
Joan,2/4/2007,blue,2010,peach,2018
John,3/22/1979,yellow,2009,plum,2000
```

I have tried declaring the year1 column as an array and then running it through an "each do" loop to change the date type, but I end up getting "ArgumentError: invalid date". I'm thinking I'm close to an answer but not quite getting there.

**Ruby Code:**

```
table = CSV.read('filename.csv', headers: true)

yr1 = p table['year1']

yr1.each do |date|
  Date.strptime(date, '%-m/-%d/%Y')
end
```

Thoughts on what I could do or what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Might be your locale. 11/17/2000 is a valid date in the US, but in many locales that isn’t valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a couple issues here, the first is a typo:

```
yr1 = p table['yearl'] # note 'l' not '1'
```

Here you are asking for the column name as **yearl** with that last character as a lowercase **L** (**l**) not the digit **1**.

Fixing the typo will still result in an **ArgumentError (invalid date)** issue because the docs for [`Date::strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) state:

> strptime does not support specification of flags and width unlike strftime.

So we need to remove the flag dashes:

```
Date.strptime(date, '%-m/-%d/%Y')
# becomes
Date.strptime(date, '%m/-%d/%Y')
```

Then we need to remove that last dash, which was likely supposed to be a flag dash. It is not a flag because it is before the percent sign (**%**), and instead is attempting to match a literal dash:

```
Date.strptime(date, '%m/-%d/%Y') # this would work if `date` was "1/-18/1989"
# becomes
Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

So now your new script looks something like:

```
require 'csv'
table = CSV.read('filename.csv', headers: true)

yr1 = p table['year1']

yr1.each do |date|
  p Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
end
```

and works. Note the 2 calls to the `p` method which can be removed and the script still works (though, obviously nothing is done with the parsed date).

Writing it back out to a file is the then pretty trivial:

```
require 'csv'
input = CSV.read('filename.csv', headers: true)

CSV.open("filename1.csv", "wb", headers: input.headers, write_headers: true) do |output|
  input.each do |row|
    row['year1'] = Date.strptime(row['year1'], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y')
    row['year2'] = Date.strptime(row['year2'], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y')
    # maybe even just these next lines for this small script, you might actually
    # need the Date object later though
    # row['year1'] = row['year1'].split('/').last
    # row['year2'] = row['year2'].split('/').last

    output << row
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you.  I think I see a problem I forgot to place in my example. Currently the dates are wrapped in quotation marks, apparently as a string (i.e. "1/1/1950"), which I believe is still causing me to receive the "ArgumentError: invalid date" result. I tried adding a .to_date method, but to no avail. I will update my example accordingly. Thoughts on a step I can do to convert the string date to a date?

Comment: @KevinHemphill even with the quotation marks all my examples run as expected with 0 changes. Are you sure all the dates in your real file are actually valid dates? Try some rescuing `ArgumentError` and outputting the row that errors out and seeing if any of the dates look funky

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out. I had some blank cells which were throwing errors. A quick begin-rescue-end added to the loop and now I'm rocking and rolling. Thank you @simplelime!

Comment: Well, I thought I was out of the weeds, but I've run into another problem. As I stated in my last comment, some rows have blanks in the year fields. I have added a begin - row['year1']... row['year2']... etc. - rescue - next - end sequence, but now when it outputs to file, I am only getting the rows that have data in both fields. It won't include rows that have blanks, which I still want. When I run the code it reads the blanks as "nil'. What can I do to make sure I get all the rows from the original file and just have this code update the dates when it finds them to year only?

Comment: @KevinHemphill you can just check with an `if` or `unless` statement to make sure you have data before you try and parse it, now that you know the problem: `row['year1'] = Date.strptime(row['year1'], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y') if row['year1']` should work. If the value is `nil` it won't try and parse year1, but if you have something in the row, it'll then try and parse it out

Comment: Perfect! I thought it was probably as simple as using an if statement, just wasn't sure where to place it. I'm still a newbie at Ruby but learning every day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "no-padded" dashes and it will work fine:

```
date = '2/7/2003'
Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y') #=> Fri, 07 Feb 2003
```

Comment: I am still getting "ArgumentError: invalid date" when I try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also had invalid date ArgumentError, solved with:

```
date.gsub!(/\//, '-')
DateTime.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%Y')
```